# I need an idea from where to start /excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to have all my employers work hours... in the photo I've make an VBA formula color cells ( 1 color cell =12 h ) only green and blue, where is "absent" I have an if formula to count all absent days.

[image: photo of excel template]

ok, now is the problem, I need an formula/vba for when the limit is reached(work limit 160h) let s say at "day 24" the cell be highlighted or something like that.

thank you very much, I don't know from where to start.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused about what you're asking : Are you manually adding the colors and want to know when the work limit is reached or do you want to automatically had the colors and stop when the work limit is reached ?

Comment: It is hard (impossible) to calculate with colors. Re-think your approach and write the number of hours instead of colors, so you can calculate (you can keep the colors for better visibility). Then you can use Conditional Formatting to format the cells when limit is exceeded

Comment: I guess OP has a `COUNTCELLCOLOR` function to count coloured cells. If so, it can be used in Conditional Formatting.

Comment: i manually adding the colors, and when the limit is reached i need to know( in my case the limit is 160) and all my colors represent 12h, if i could highlight the day,, from template or in another sheet to be an text with " Peter- limit reached at day 24 march..

Comment: @EganWolf Eh didn't see that formula. Of course you can use that to calculate and use in Conditional Formatting.

Comment: yes the formula is countcellcolor... how to use with conditional format?

Comment: A rethink of the logic is required. Your metric is a number, but your indicator is a colour. What happens if the MS Theme changes, and all your colours change? Do all your base calculations in numbers and then conditionally format. (` if sum(#s)>160 then Colour 1, otherwise if(#) = x, Colour 2, else Colour 3`) which can all be done in native Excel, no VBA required.

Answer (score 0):

workflow :

1, get lastRow from datasheet

2, for i=3 To lastRow do : process all columns in row (for ii=1), if cell(column, row).color is GREEN or BLUE add 12 hrs to counter, if counter reach 160, you will have in which column it reaches in ii

Comment: hmm, i can upload the template somewhere to understand what are you saying ?:D or if you can be more explicit please

Comment: hmm, I thought my answer is clearly enough.. first process first row.. so column by column for rowNo3.. declare counter As Integer = 0... If cell.Color is Blue Or Green, counter = counter + 12.. If it reaches 160, you will have info in which column for rowNo3 it reaches.. Then you can apply colour to that cell

Answer (score 0):

Here, put this on the "ThisWorkbook" module in the VBA developpment Windows

It check for the color everytime you open the Workbook. If the hour limit is reached, it will color the remaining cells and the name of the employee in grey.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim i As Long, y As Long
Dim Check As Integer

For i = 3 To 7
Check = 0
    For y = 2 To 32

    'Replace this one with the green RGB
    If Cells(i, y).Interior.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142) Then
    Check = Check + 1
    End If

    'Replace this one with the blue RGB
    If Cells(i, y).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192) Then
    Check = Check + 1
    End If

    '12*13 = 156, the closet to 160
    If Check >= 13 Then
        Cells(i, y + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    End If

    Next
Next

End Sub
```

You may want to add a button on the sheet that launch the macro when you click on it so you can easily do it manually.

I know this code isn't optimised, I'll let you play with it, but it's a pretty solid start

Also, replace marked RGB with your actual color. I tried to find which one it was, but I'm colorblind, so ...

Comment: Please note that `Dim i, y As Integer` only declares `y As Integer` but `i As Variant`. You must specify a type for **every** variable in VBA: `Dim i As Integer, y As Integer`. And just in case to be safe you should use `Long` for row counting variables since Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: I didn't knew for i ! It's edited. OP seems to have only a few rows, I didn't thought it would be necessary to have them as Long.

Comment: I will try that, but note( în the photo i put only march month, it will continue wit April, May, etc i need to put a range in your code?

Comment: Yeah you should had something to find the Last Row to use on i

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use conditional formatting, I can't give you exact answer because I don't know how your `COUNTCELLCOLOR` works, but you can work with this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")&ROW()))>160
```

This one will sum all cells in row from first column to current (the one where this formula is placed or for which the conditional formatting test is checked) and check if it is bigger then 160. You must change the `SUM` to `COUNTCELLCOLOR` and tune it to your needs (maybe subtract 1 from `COLUMN()`, etc.).

Edit: Check this as a test formula for conditional formatting:

```
=CountCellsByColor(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")&ROW()),B11)+CountCellsByColor(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")&ROW()),B12)>13
```

Comment: / this is vba code for count.  Function CountCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long
 
    Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent
 
    CountCellsByColor = cntRes
End Function

Comment: I will try your solution, and i will notify you. Thank you!

Comment: it work, but doesn`t stop me or announce me when the limit is reached.. it only say true or false, and i need to check manually at what date the limit was reached.